# NumPy analog of R's `filter`

Tags: python, r, numpy, interpolation

What is analog of R's [`filter`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/filter.html) in NumPy?

I have the following R code:

```
f <- rep(1/9, 9)
smth_x <- filter(x, f, sides=2)
```

Where `x` is some 1-D timeseries vector which may contain `nan`'s.

How to perform the same operation using NumPy? (or any other python libs)

Comment: note that `filter` is in the `dplyr` package -- not base R

Comment: actually, I was wrong.  There *is* a `filter` in `dplyr`, but now that I look again I see that OP is looking for a convolution function (`stats::filter`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [scipy filter functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) do what you want, in particular [lfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html). Going from [this HOWTO](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/ApplyFIRFilter):

```
import numpy, scipy.signal
taps = numpy.repeat(1.0/9, 9)
smoothed_x = scipy.signal.lfilter(taps, 1.0, x)
```

Comment: you should probably expand your answer a bit -- link-only questions are deprecated.